# C# app.config with multiple values with a delimited value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, app-config

I have my `app.config` file with an `ArrayOfString` entry. Each entry contains a semi-colon delimited string. I want to be able to use lambda, if possible, to parse out the values from a `List<>` based on input criteria. But I want the first entry it finds bases on that criteria. Or is there a better way **USING** the `app.config` file?

For instance ..

If I wanted to find the first entry that contained the `[source],[filetype]` and just return the file path.

Example `app.config` entry.

```
SOURCE;FLAC;112;2;\\sourcepath\music\

DEST;FLAC;112;2;\\destpath\music\
```

Comment: You can use ConfigurationManager to get values from app.config. If you want to go with this solution - are all the entries of this structure, i.e. source, something, number, number, path ? If so, you could create an object and instantiate it with the values - then filtering would be pretty easy. What is an example text that you would be looking for ? Is it 'SOURCE;FLAC' or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on having your values fall at the correct index of a string split operation, you should create your own `ConfigurationSection` definition.

See the [How To on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) and the [MSDN ConfigurationProperty example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8ww86kz).

Here is some code to get you started:

```
class CustomConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    private readonly CustomElementCollection entries =
        new CustomElementCollection();

    [ConfigurationProperty("customEntries", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CustomElementCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
    public CustomElementCollection CustomEntries { get { return entries; } }
}

class CustomElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public CustomElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (CustomElement) BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new CustomElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((CustomElement)element).Name;
    }
}

class CustomElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this["name"] as string; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("direction", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Direction
    {
        get { return this["direction"] as string; }
        set { this["direction"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("filePath", IsRequired = true)]
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return this["filePath"] as string; }
        set { this["filePath"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Once you have your custom configuration specified, then you can `Select` with a lambda using any property specified in your custom `ConfigurationElement`.